# Can't partition my SSD because of an immovable object

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, arch-linux

I wanted to dual-boot arch with win 10, but I can't shrink my partition because of the file further down. I've searched the internet and found that it has to do something with Intel's Software Guard, so I'm kinda hesitating to delete it. Do you guys have any tips as to how I can fix the problem?

Description:
A volume shrink analysis was initiated on volume (C:). This event log entry details information about the last unmovable file that could limit the maximum number of reclaimable bytes.

Diagnostic details:
 - The last unmovable file appears to be: \ProgramData\Intel\IntelSGXPSW:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION
 - The last cluster of the file is: 0x35373bc
 - Shrink potential target (LCN address): 0xd371b3
 - The NTFS file flags are: ----I

Comment: That is a heavily secured folder (I have it here) and most assuredly should not be deleted. Either you need a bigger disk (to allow different space for the dual boot).  Either that or consider using a virtual application for either Windows 10 or Linux

Comment: @John I used a 3rd-party software to shrink my drive. Quite interestingly all of the 3rd party ones are Chinese. I probably should've used GParted, but whatever...

Comment: This is the Intel SGX 'secure enclave' - I have no idea how to remove that file.